# Qt5 with OpenCV2.4.10

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I want to use OpenCV on Qt5. So, in my Qt project, in the QtTest.pro, I worte

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\
INCLUDEPATH += C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv
INCLUDEPATH += C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\opencv2

LIBS += -LC:/OpenCV/opencv/build/x86/vc12/lib \
    -lopencv_calib3d2410d \
    -lopencv_contrib2410d \
    -lopencv_core2410d \
    -lopencv_features2d2410d \
    -lopencv_flann2410d \
    -lopencv_gpu2410d \
    -lopencv_highgui2410d \
    -lopencv_imgproc2410d \
    -lopencv_legacy2410d \
    -lopencv_ml2410d \
    -lopencv_nonfree2410d \
    -lopencv_objdetect2410d \
    -lopencv_ocl2410d \
    -lopencv_photo2410d \
    -lopencv_stitching2410d \
    -lopencv_superres2410d \
    -lopencv_ts2410d \
    -lopencv_videostab2410d \
    -lopencv_videostab2410d
```

and in my main.cpp, I worite

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

But when I run it, it had a link error,

D:\QtTest\main.cpp:3: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/core/core.hpp': No such file or directory

So do somebody knows how to fix it?

Comment: add opencv include directory to additional include directories in your project settings

Answer (score 0):

write an directory paths like

C:/OpenCV/opencv/build/include/

or

C:\OpenCV\opencv\build\include\